# Solution of $ydx-xdy=xydy-x^2 dx$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve

> $ydx-xdy=xydy-x^2dx$

I divided both sides by $y^2$ and obtained 
$$\frac{d(\frac{x}{y})}{\frac{x}{y}}=\frac{y.dy-x.dx}{y}$$

How should we solve right hand side here

Comment: Are you sure that there is no typo in $y. dx-x.dy=xy .dy-x^2 .dx$ ?.

Comment: Put $v=\frac{x}{y} \implies \frac{dx}{dy} = v + y\frac{dv}{dy}$

Comment: The change $v=\frac{x}{y}$ is of no use because the ODE isn't homogeneous.

Comment: $y=x$ is a solution

Answer (score 3):

$$ydx - xdy = xydy - x^2 dx$$
$$\frac{ydx - xdy}{x} = ydy - xdx$$
$$\frac{ydx - xdy}{x\sqrt{y^2 - x^2}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}d(y^2 - x^2)}{\sqrt{y^2 - x^2}}$$
$$\frac{ydx - xdy}{x^2\sqrt {\frac{y^2}{x^2} - 1}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}d(y^2 - x^2)}{\sqrt{y^2 - x^2}}$$
$$\frac{d(y/x)}{\sqrt {(\frac{y}{x})^2 - 1}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}d(y^2 - x^2)}{\sqrt{y^2 - x^2}}$$
$$\ln \left|\frac{y}{x} + \sqrt{(\frac{y}{x})^2 - 1}\right| = \sqrt{y^2 - x^2}  + c$$

Comment: Dividing both sides by $\sqrt{y^2-x^2}$ means your solution, in which the left hand side could be written as arcosh$\dfrac{y}{x}$, is only valid for |y|>|x|. For |y|<|x| you get an arcos function instead.

Answer (score 1):

$$ydx-xdy=xydy-x^2dx$$
$$(y+x^2)2xdx=2x^2(y+1)dy$$
Let : $\quad u=x^2$
$$(y+u)du=2u(y+1)dy$$
$$(y+u)\frac{du}{dy}=2(y+1)u$$
This non-linear ODE is solvable, but the solution is very complicated :
http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28y%2Bu%28y%29%29u%27%28y%29%3D2%28y%2B1%29u%28y%29&x=7&y=7

That is why I suspect a typo in the wording of the question if it is a training exercise. Or the exercise asks for something else, which can be answered without solving the ODE.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's not homogenous, the substitution $y=ux$ works nicely, giving $$(u^2-1)\frac{dx}{du}+ux=-1,$$ which can be solved using an integrating factor: multiply through by $(u^2-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ or $(1-u^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, depending on whether you want solutions in the $|y|>|x|$ or $|y|<|x|$ domain (separated by the solutions $y=\pm x$).

Answer (score 0):

$$
ydx - xdy = xydy - x^2 dx.
$$
Dividing both sides by $dy$
$$
y\frac{dx}{dy} - x = xy - x^2\frac{dx}{dy}.
$$
Dividing both side by $x^2$
$$
\begin{split}
-\frac{x - y\dfrac{dx}{dy}}{x^2} &= \dfrac{y}{x} - \frac{dx}{dy}\\
-\frac{d\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)}{dy} &= \dfrac{y}{x} - \frac{dx}{dy}
\end{split}
$$
Now taking substitution
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{y}{x} &= t,\\ 
\frac{dx}{dy} &= \left(\frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{t^2}\frac{dt}{dy}\right)
\end{split}
$$
so, the equation after taking LCM and all becomes
$$
\begin{split}
-t^2 \frac{dt}{dy} &= t^3 - t - \frac{dt}{dy}\\
\frac{dt}{dy}(1-t^2) &= -t(1-t^2)\\
\frac{dt}{t} &= -dy
\end{split}
$$
Integrate both side
$$
\ln|t| = -y + C
$$
substituting $t=\frac{y}{x}$ again
$$
y = \ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) + C
$$

Comment: Sorry I dont really know coding

Comment: Please read the short help on formulas that is provided in the edit window. The first step is really trivial, enclose every (complete) formula in `$...$` or `$$...$$`. The next is not that trivial, but similarly important, enclose any exponent or part of a fraction larger than a single letter in `{...}`. Everything else you can explore later.

Comment: I think your line $\dfrac{dx}{dy} = \left(\dfrac{1}{t} - \dfrac{1}{t^2}\dfrac{dt}{dy}\right)$ should be $\dfrac{dx}{dy} = \left(\dfrac{1}{t} - \dfrac{y}{t^2}\dfrac{dt}{dy}\right)$.

Comment: @mcd why do you think so, if you did not understand what I wrote I'll tell you again
$$ y/x = t$$
$$x=y/t$$
now differentiating both sides WRT y gives you
$$dx/dy = d(y/t)/dy$$
now just use the standard quotient rule

Comment: Using the quotient rule, I get $$\frac{d}{dy}\Big(\frac{y}{t} \Big)=  \frac{1\cdot t - y \cdot \frac{dt}{dy}}{t^2}$$